# Splitting a list so duplicates fall within the same sub list

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I have a list of items that I would like to partition into even sized sub-lists for asynchronous processing. However, it's required that items of the same value are processed synchronously, so I need an efficient mechanism to ensure that items of the same value are grouped into the same sub-list, preferably in the same order they appear in the source list.

So with this example...

```
public class ListItem
{
    public ListItem(string key)
    {
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public string Key;
}

private void Sample()
{
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("A"),
        new ListItem("B"),
        new ListItem("C"),
        new ListItem("D"),
        new ListItem("A"),
        new ListItem("B"),
        new ListItem("E"),
        new ListItem("F"),
        new ListItem("G"),
    };

    List<List<ListItem>> sublists = Partition(list, 3);
}

private List<List<ListItem>> Partition(List<ListItem> list, int batchSize)
{
    // Split list logic
}
```

The Partition method would produce three sub-lists something similar to

- A, A, C
- B, B, D
- E, F, G

It would also be very useful if the code were flexible enough to allow grouping on more than one list item property.

Thanks

Comment: If you are doing asynchronous processing, why do they have to be even-sized?

Comment: Is it important that B and B will be one after another? or are you just looking for a way to prevent them from running at the same time?

Comment: I am assuming batchSize is how many sub-lists you want?

Comment: It's important that the first item B is fully processes before the second.

Comment: Batch size is the max number of items is each sub list.

Comment: Look up [dynamic task parallelism in the TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx) and the plethora of concurrent collections that may suit your needs.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, the downstream processing is DB/IO heavy. Splitting the list and processing asynchronously via a limited number of concurrent DB connections seems to yield significant performance improvements. However, if items with the same key exist in separate lists, the DB operations interfere with each other. I’m not trying to process in parallel threads (TPL), since processing async in a single thread seems to be sufficient, and I don’t wish to create threads unnecessarily. Also, after checking, I’m not aware of anything in TPL which actually does what I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public ListItem(string key) { Key=key; }
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list=new List<ListItem>() 
        {
            new ListItem("A"),
            new ListItem("B"),
            new ListItem("C"),
            new ListItem("D"),
            new ListItem("A"),
            new ListItem("B"),
            new ListItem("E"),
            new ListItem("F"),
            new ListItem("G"),
        };

        var sublists=Partition(list, 3);
        // 0: A, A, C
        // 1: B, B, D
        // 3: E, F, G
    }

    static List<List<ListItem>> Partition(IEnumerable<ListItem> list, int batchSize)
    {
        // create empty lists of batches
        var partitions=new List<List<ListItem>>();
        // group items with same key together
        var lookup=list.ToLookup((item) => item.Key);
        foreach(var group in lookup)
        {
            // Get array of same items (called a flock)
            ListItem[] flock=lookup[group.Key].ToArray();
            if(flock.Length>batchSize)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Batch Size is too small for grouping", "batchSize");
            }
            //Find first batch with available space from existing ones
            var batch=partitions.FirstOrDefault((part) => (batchSize-part.Count)>=flock.Length);
            if(batch!=null)
            {
                batch.AddRange(flock);
            }
            else // otherwise create a new batch
            {
                partitions.Add(new List<ListItem>(flock));
            }
        }
        return partitions;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not ensure all batches are of the same length. It only ensures they are not _more_ than `batchSize` long.

Comment: Thanks ja72. I'll run this through a few tests and report back :)

Comment: Maybe tweak it whereas if the `batchSize` is too small, instead of throwing an exception in splits the `flock` into two batches.

Comment: I've not be able to fully test performance but the solution certainly functions as I hoped. I'm not sure splitting the flock when over batch size will work as matches need to be processed as a single batch i.e. synchronously, in sequence. I will probably just have to accept that if a flock overflows, that batch size will just have to grow to match. But it should be an extremely rare occurrence which I can log a tweak if necessary.